# Geodesics on spheroid

Tags: geometry, differential-geometry, self-learning, geodesic

Describe the geodesics

A **Spheroid** obtained by rotating the ellipse $\frac{x^2}{p^2}+\frac{z^2}{q^2}=1$ around the z-axis where $p, q\gt 0$

[image]

Please explain this question explicitly. Thank you:)

Comment: What have you tried until now? You just have to compute the differential equation of the geodesic. Have you already computed the Christoffel symbols or the connection matrix?

Comment: None of the comments and answers mentioned the key point: for a general surface, it is hopeless to find geodesics, the geodesic equations just give  a messy system of 2nd order non-linear ODE's. An important exception is a surface of revolution, as in your case, where you can use the Clairaut equation (see Wikipedia under Clairaut relation).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all you need to know what is the connection you want to compute the geodesics of. If you want a metric connection you must know the metric at play, which in most cases will be the one induced by embedding in $R^3$.

Once you know that you can solve the geodesics equation with respect to appropriate coordinates and find an analytic expression for them, or just give that equation as a more implicit answer: depending on which degree of description you seek.

I would suggest trying cylindrical coordinates to begin with, sincr it should be easier to show the required property.

Answer (score 2):

There is an excellent account on [this Wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geodesics_on_an_ellipsoid#Geodesics_on_an_ellipsoid_of_revolution). The first two-thirds of the article cover ellipsoids of revolution (which is what you have).